# What is the best way to "predefine" a path for an object that the player can control

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I have the following problem: 
Imagine playing a 2D jump 'n' run game in a 3D world. You can only go left- and right. But the path you walk isnt a straight line. There are curves. So looking at this image:
[image]

It may be a bit clearer what I want. Simply by clicking the "right" key, my Sphere should move along the black line.
How do I accomplish this?

1. How do I move the sphere (I am guessing a simple `.AddForce`) and...
2. How do I make it go along the black line.

Remember that the sphere should be still able to jump. So there is no restriction in the Y-Axis.

Comment: Egads. How *would* I go about doing this? I'd probably start with some kind of Tweening system that let me define paths by creating splines. Then I'd let the character tween towards the start or end of the path only when the player is pressing keys... I did something like this once (for enemies), but I don't remember what Tween engine I used.

Comment: id (ab)use the inbuilt unity navigation system and create a special, invisible mesh (=a gameobject with only meshfilter attached) for the navmesh agent to walk on. well actually id use runtime navmesh building and not have that gameobject thing, but thats a whole lot more complex and poorly documented. get more infos on both options here unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/s/navigation